# Teradata - Convert timestamp from UTC to Eastern, column seen as Eastern by system

Tags: teradata

I've searched all over StackExchange and the TD forums, but I cannot find an answer to the question mentioned in the title.

The timestamp in the table I need to work with is in UTC. However, TD believes the timestamp is Eastern as that is the system time.

This query then returns the same timestamps (and shouldn't):

```
SELECT
     TIMESTAMP_X
     ,TIMESTAMP_X AT 'America Eastern'
FROM
     TABLE_A
```

I'm looking for a method to set `TIMESTAMP_X` to UTC, and then convert to Eastern without using interval math (dataset will encompass years).

Comment: Can you post table definition for the timestamp column ? (HELP TABLE DbName.TABLE_A, or SHOW TABLE)

Comment: Cluster is moving @ snails pace - running HELP statement now.

Comment: TIMESTAMP_X = TIMESTAMP(6)

Comment: Try `TIMESTAMP_X AT 0`

Comment: @dnoeth I'm not trying to convert the data to UTC (it already is). I need to join these records to another table where the timestamps are Eastern. Since I believe this issue comes from the creation of the table itself, I've resorted to converting the other tables to UTC and then converting back to Eastern.